# How to add label to custom field component in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

So I have created a custom field for react admin which looks something like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRecordContext } from "react-admin";


export const IsOnline = (props:{view:string}) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    
    if (record.is_online)
        return <span className={props.view}>{("Online")}</span>;

    return <span className={props.view}>{("Offline")}</span>;
};
export default IsOnline;
```

And using it like this:

```
import IsOnline from "./IsOnline.field";
<Datagrid hover={false} rowClick="edit">
(...)
<IsOnline view="list"/> // <-- Here I would normally add the "label" prop
</Datagrid>
(...)
```

The react-admin documentation claims that

> [Tip: Note that the label property can be used on any field to customize the field label.](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#adding-search-and-filters-to-the-list)

What am I missing then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turned out to be quite simple by adding the "label" property on the custom field:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRecordContext } from "react-admin";


export const IsOnline = (props:{view:string, label:string}) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();

    if (record.is_online)
        return <span className={props.view}>{("Online")}</span>;

    return <span className={props.view}>{("Offline")}</span>;
};
export default IsOnline;
```

And in the datagrid:

```
<IsOnline view="list" label="Status"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `<Labeled>` component as shown here:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#setting-a-field-label

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Labeled.html

Comment: This adds the label for the column but also ads the label around each record :(